# how to add font-awesome icon in wordpress wp_nav_menu()

Tags: wordpress

[image: nav menu image]

I am trying to show this menu in wordpress using wp_nav_menu(); but due to less knowledge i can't understand how to do this task.
kindly help me and please share code if you have any idea.

```
<div class="pull-left">
<nav>
<ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow l_tinynav1" id="nav">
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="first-level-link sf-with-ul">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">Home</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=4" class="first-level-link">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">About Us</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=6" class="first-level-link">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-cogs icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">Services</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=8" class="first-level-link">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-briefcase icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">Projects</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=10" class="first-level-link">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-key icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">Careers</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=12" class="first-level-link">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-comments icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">FAQ</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=14" class="first-level-link">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-envelope-alt icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">Contact</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

now i am using this but its static and one more thing i am also facing active menu issue too. please share code with me or telme how can i add active class in static menu which one is clicked so show this is your position now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="pull-left">
              <nav>
                <ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow l_tinynav1" id="nav">
                  <?php echo $page_id = $post->ID; ?>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="first-level-link <?php if(is_home()){ echo "active"; }?> sf-with-ul">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">Home</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=4" class="first-level-link <?php if($page_id==4){echo "active";}?> ">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">About Us</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=6" class="first-level-link <?php if($page_id==6){echo "active";}?>">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-cogs icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">Services</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=8" class="first-level-link <?php if($page_id==8){echo "active";}?>">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-briefcase icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">Projects</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=10" class="first-level-link <?php if($page_id==10){echo "active";}?>">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-key icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">Careers</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=12" class="first-level-link <?php if($page_id==12){echo "active";}?>">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-comments icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">FAQ</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li class="first-level-li"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?page_id=14" class="first-level-link <?php if($page_id==14){echo "active";}?>">
                    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="icon-envelope-alt icon-large"></i></div>
                    <div class="menu-item-wrapper">
                      <div class="first-level-li-text-link">Contact</div>
                    </div>
                    </a> </li>
                </ul>

              </nav>
            </div>
```

active class added using custom code.

Answer (score 3):

This process is simple nowadays.

Goto your wordpress dashboard then select appearance->editor
and select your theme header.php file.

add this line in the header section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

after adding the above line go to appearance->menu then add the Fa Icon codes beside you menu items

```
<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

hope this help

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been searching for hours on how to integrate it with wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the markup above, you can simply change the `icon-key icon-large` classes to reflect those of FontAwesome.

For example, the 'home' icon, which is represented with a house.  So, simply replace `icon-home icon-large` with `fa fa-home`.

A list of the FontAwesome icons are available [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/), click one to see it's class.

If you wish to use a dynamic menu then `wp_nav_menu` is probably not for you.  You may find it easier to build your own using [wp_get_nav_menu_items](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items).  There is a brilliant example on that link of exactly how to do it.

Comment: i am using the above markup and its shows exactly same in wordpress but its static code i guess, now problem is that when i am calling menu dynamically using wp_nav_menu(); then icons didn't shows. and one more thing if you have any idea about how to add active class in above html code kindly share with me. thanks.

Comment: In that case you need to amend the markup.  The easiest way to do this is to build the menu yourself using [wp_get_nav_menu_items](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items).  I'll edit the answer to reflect this.